# How to create a new script file via Apps Script & Drive SDK

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Trying to create a new project with files with a call to the Drive SDK within Apps Script.

Where exactly would the following go in a `UrlFetchApp` request...

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "id":"9basdfbd-749a-4as9b-b9d1-d64basdf803",
      "name":"Code",
      "type":"server_js",
      "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
    },
    {
      "id":"3asf7c0d-1afb-4a9-8431-5asdfc79e7ae",
      "name":"index",
      "type":"html",
      "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    New message!!\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's from the [import/export docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/import-export) and in the [example video](http://youtu.be/lEVMu9KE6jk?t=3m5s) Dan mentions the calls are for languages outside of Apps Script but requesting a list of script file types and the content of those files [does work](https://script.google.com/d/1rxooF5Ys7JuTUHeOWeQ-uifJPpp31VS2JcZ9YiHenC6zGd7r5hqXs2K2/edit?usp=sharing) once the authorization is setup with Eric's oAuth2 library.

My most recent guess...

```js
function createProject( ) {
  var token = getDriveService().getAccessToken(); // from Eric's oAuth2 lib

  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=true';

  // Where does this go?
  var files = {
    "files": [
      {
        "name":"Code",
        "type":"server_js",
        "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
      },
      {
        "name":"index",
        "type":"html",
        "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    Hello, world!!\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
      }
    ]
  };

  // Where does this go too?
  var metadata = {
    'title': 'script-test1',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.script',
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": "0B2VkNbQMTnaCODBRVjZQcXBXckU"
      }
    ],
  };

  var options = {
    'headers' : {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.google-apps.script+json',
    },
    'method' : 'POST',
    'payload' : files  // probably not right

  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());

}
```

An untitled Drive file of unknown type does get created and the payload does get inserted into it, but it's not converted to a script file type.

Going another route and just using...

```
var file = {
    "title": "Test script",
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script",
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": "[INSERT FOLDER ID HERE]"
      }
    ]
  };

Drive.Files.insert(file);
```

...throws an Internal error.

Also aware of the [Drive insert docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) that have a client-side JS example, but don't know how much of it should be translated over (if possible) to server-side Apps Script.

Comment: In your options variable, try changing the payload parameter for 'body:', and forget about the metadata.

Comment: a new Drive file of unknown type still gets created but no text or anything is inserted. i don't see `body` as an advanced parameter in [UrlFetchApp docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) and interpret `payload` as the equivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, but you have a few mistakes. Your first approach (using `UrlFetch`) has some errors in the `options` variable.  Here's a doGet() function that (after verifying authorization) creates a new Apps Script Project and writes the UrlFetch response to the page:

```
function doGet() {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  if (!driveService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = driveService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplate(
        '<a href="<?= authorizationUrl ?>" target="_blank">Authorize</a>. ' +
        'Refresh the page when authorization complete.');
    template.authorizationUrl = authorizationUrl;
    var page = template.evaluate();
    return page;
  } else {     
    var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=true";   
    var requestBody =  {
      "files": [
        {
          "name":"Code",
          "type":"server_js",
          "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
        },
        {
          "name":"index",
          "type":"html",
         "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    Created with Apps Script.\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
        }
      ]
    };

    var options = {
      "headers": {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  driveService.getAccessToken(),
       }, 
      "contentType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json",
      "method" : "post",
      "payload": JSON.stringify(requestBody)
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response.getContentText());
  }
}
```

This code creates an Apps Script project file called "Untitled" in the root Drive folder. The `options` object should specify POST as the method for creating projects (default is GET), and the payload needs to be converted to a string from a JSON object to be understood by `UrlFetch`.

Alternatively, you can do the same thing by using the Advanced Drive Service in Apps Script instead of `UrlFetch`. The following code creates the same Apps Script project (but places it in the specified folder and names the file 'Test script'):

```
function createGoogleFileInFolder3() {  
    var requestBody =  {
      "files": [
        {
          "name":"Code",
          "type":"server_js",
          "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
        },
        {
          "name":"index",
          "type":"html",
          "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    Created with Apps Script.\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
        }
      ]
    };

  var resource = {
    "title": "Test script",
    "parents": [
      {
        "id": "<parent folder id here>"
      }
    ]
  };

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(requestBody), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");

  Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {"convert":"true"});
}
```

Comment: `Utilities.newBlob()` is what I was missing out on. Thought the blob had to come from a `response.getBlob()` for some reason. Will implement in my add-on. thx a ton!

Comment: wait, did you manually insert the conversions for the unicode `\u003c` or did you use a library / mapping for that?

Comment: I would like to do this with Drive.Files.update(recource, fileId, blob) but I get  "The app does not have the required scope to update Apps Scripts."

?

Comment: Using the Advanced Drive Service does not work, because you cannot set your custom token for it and can't have Apps Script ask it for you  :(

Comment: The optional query parameter `convert` for the `upload` method is now deprecated.  It has no function. [Reference - Parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#parameters)

Comment: Sandy, the page you link to is for Drive.update; this sample is using Drive.insert, for which the convert parameter is still valid (at least for Drive v2): [Reference - Drive.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#parameters)