# Update (Overwrite) one Apps Script file with another Apps Script file using Apps Script Code

Tags: google-apps-script

Overwrite file.  Overwrite Apps Script file.

This is **not** a question to *create* a new Apps Script file.  That won't help me.  I need to ***update*** an existing Apps Script file.  This question is similar to creating a new file, but it's not the same issue.  The syntax for an update, and the requirements for an update may be different enough from creating a new file, that I can't get a solution from the answer about creating a new file.  I've looked at an answer for creating a new file, and that has not answered my question.

I have tried using the Advanced Drive Service to update an existing Apps Script file with another Apps Script file.

```
function updateMyScript() {
  var targetFileID = 'File ID';

  var dataSource = {
    "files": [
      {
        "id":"739a57da-f77c-4e1a-96df-7d86ef227d62",
        "name":"Code",
        "type":"server_js",
        "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
      },
      {
        "id":"2c7e8b5a-dbc5-4cd2-80e9-77b6291b3167",
        "name":"index",
        "type":"html",
        "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    New message!!\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
      }
    ]
  };

  var filesResource = Drive.Files.get(targetFileID);
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.stringify(dataSource), "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json");
  var whatRezult = Drive.Files.update(filesResource, targetFileID, blob, {"convert":"true"});

  Logger.log('whatRezult: ' + whatRezult);
};
```

The `id` properties in the `dataSource` object are id's of each specific `.gs` or `html` file inside of the project.  I got those id's by downloading the "target" Apps Script file to JSON, then opening up the JSON file and copying out the file id's.  So, I know that those are correct.  I'd like a way to retrieve those individual file ID's from the project with code.  The post about creating a ***new*** apps script file, does not explain how to get the "sub" ID's from the project file.  The project file ID is not the same as each file ID inside of the project.  The `name` and `type` properties are obvious.  And there are only two types of files which, from the example, have types of `server_js` and "html".  It looks like the `source` for the internal files to the Apps Script project file can be a string literal.  So, you can just type in whatever you want the replacement content to be.

The `target ID` is self explanatory.

If there is a way to do this with either the Advanced Drive Service or `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` that will answer my question.  I only want to use Apps Script.  So, I'm not looking for a solution written in some other language, or that is run from outside of Apps Script.

With the above code, I'm getting an error from the next to last line:

```
Drive.Files.update(filesResource, targetFileID, blob, {"convert":"true"});
```

The error is:

> The app does not have the required scope to update Apps Scripts.

So, obviously, it's looking for a scope setting to be indicated somewhere.  I'm guessing that it would go into the the fourth parameter for the options.

Comment: Henrique pointed out in the comments of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27137870/1480465) that setting the needed `drive.scripts` scope isn't possible via the `Drive.Files.Update()` route, so the mult-step `UrlFetchApp()` process is the only way as provided in the answers here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ask for the special Drive-AppsScript [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts
```

Since you cannot tell Apps Script to ask this scope for you (it determines its own scopes automatically by analyzing your code). You need to do the oAuth dance yourself (by using [Eric's lib](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) for example). But then since you also cannot set this token you retrieved yourself for the script to use in its built-in or advanced service calls (not that I know of anyway), you'll have to do the UrlFetch call manually too, and pass your "custom" token in the header (like shown in the "[create new script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096302/how-to-create-a-new-script-file-via-apps-script-drive-sdk)" question.

The UrlFetch call to `update` is very similar to the `insert` one. Just change the method to `PUT` and add the apps script project id in the path.

```js
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/" + scriptID;
var requestBody = ...; //the same
var options = {
  "headers": {
     'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  yourManuallyFetchedToken,
   }, 
  "contentType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script+json",
  "method" : "PUT", //changed here from POST to PUT
  "payload": JSON.stringify(requestBody)
}
```

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct, and awarding you the bonus points.  I've gotten something to work, and determined that the requestBody needs to have the file id in it.  I've provided an answer that includes other information.  Your information about the scope, url, and method is critical to the success of this.  So, it was helpful.  There's a lot more to getting it to actually work, but to provide all of that info would be "to broad" for a question.  Have you ever successfully updated an existing Apps Script file, and have a new file inserted?  E.g.  You add a new HTML file to the source.

Comment: No, I've never done this from apps-script itself. In node-js I always replace all files.

Comment: This can be simplified as apps script now supports editing scopes https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes

Answer (score 3):

I've created a GitHub repository of a project that will update one Apps Script file (the target) from a source Apps Script file.  It's totally free to copy and use.

[GitHub Repository - apps-script-update](https://github.com/Blueprinter/Update-Apps-Script)

See the Read Me file in the GitHub repository for instructions

The code at GitHub is using the newer Apps Script API, which is different from the original answer.

Comment: `drive` scope should cover `drive.readonly`, therefore making it unnecessary in your listing.

Comment: retrieving the file ids were still only obtained through a manual download of the json file as mentioned back in the question and not from a fetch response, right?

Comment: The gitHub code is a Web App with a file picker.  The only manual thing needed to be done with that App, is to create files with the same name in the target project, as is in the source project (Apps Script file).

Answer (score 2):

The new Apps Script API now allows for an Apps Script project to be updated.  The project that is updated can be bound to a document.  (Sheet, Form, Doc)  This code uses the REST API, and makes a PUT request from Apps Script code using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)`  This code is being run from an Apps Script file to update another Apps Script file.

The Apps Script API must be enabled for the Apps Script file running the code.  The Apps Script API is enabled in the Google Cloud console.  From the code editor, choose "Resources" and "Cloud Platform project"  Search for Apps Script API and enable it.

```
function updateContent(scriptId,content,theAccessTkn) {
//try{
  var options,payload,response,url;

  if (!content) {
    //Error handling function
    return;
  }

  if (!theAccessTkn) {
    theAccessTkn = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  }

  //https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent
  url = "https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + scriptId + "/content";

  options = {
    "method" : "PUT",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "headers": {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  theAccessTkn
     },
    "contentType": "application/json",//If the content type is set then you can stringify the payload
    "payload": JSON.stringify(content)
  };

  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  response = JSON.parse(response);//Must be parsed even though it shows as coming back as an object

  //Logger.log('typeof response: ' + typeof response)

  //Logger.log('response 29 in file GS_Update: ' + JSON.stringify(response).slice(0,45))

  return response;
//} catch(e) {
  //Logger.log(response)
//}
};
```

You must use the correct scopes in order for the code to run without an authorization error.

The scopes can be set in the appsscript.json file.  To view the appsscript.json file, you must first click the View menu, and choose the "Show manifest" menu item.

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

The first time that the Apps Script API is used, the PUT request may not work, and will return an error with a link to the Google Cloud console.  That's why it's important to view the return response `Logger.log('typeof response: ' + typeof response)` from the `response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);` statement.

Comment: Is it possible to load only one script file without destroying the rest?

Comment: Yes, but you need to get all the original files from the target file, update the one file that you want to change, and then write all the files back to the target.  There's no built-in option to update just one inner file in the project file.  So, it's a matter of knowing how the JSON of the Apps Script file is structured, and updating the JSON object.

Comment: I found it pretty easy just to copy the source and destination jsons, parse them, append the desired files and then write it back it the destination project.

Comment: Files can also be removed, for example if you were copying files from a development file to a production file, and there were files in your development file that you didn't need in the production project.