# Google Apps Script Library and Script Distribution

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers, libraries, add-on

i was wondering if there is a possibility to distribute my Custom Script to all the sheets in my workspace. I came upon different ways with libraries or Add-ons, but they all lack some points i want to accomplish.

1. I want it to be private only for my Google Account
2. I need it to run the onOpen(e) Trigger for every File on my Sheets Account
   (So i can add a custom menu to all my Files)
3. I also need to set a time Trigger for each File so my main() Function runs every night (right now i always create a new trigger when i rerun my main Function)

So far i can use the Library Option and create a new Script for all my Files and call my Main Function out of that Library. This Workaround does not include an onOpen Trigger event. When i use the Ability of **run->test as addon** and manually add all new Files (which come up every new month) i also lack the possibility of trigger functions.

If you have Solution Ideas I'd be very happy.

BR NJ

Answer (score 2):

- An Add-on can be published privately. [Private Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/publication-categories#private_add-ons)
- A Library is private by default - The only way that someone outside of your account can use your script as a library, is to set the file sharing to allow them to use it.  [Gaining access to a library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#gaining_access_to_a_library_and_including_it_in_your_project)
- A Library can not run a simple trigger, but an Add-on can.  The reserved function name onOpen() can't be triggered by a library.  [See Table - Resource Scoping](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#resource_scoping)
- An Add-on can run the onOpen() function
- An Add-on can create an add-on menu.
- An Add-on can create one time-based trigger for each document it is installed in.  Quote: "Each add-on can only have one trigger of each type, per user, per document" [Add-on Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#restrictions_2)

If you want to do something like overwrite an Apps Script file, that can be done with the Apps Script API.  Even script projects that are bound to a document (Sheets, Forms, Docs) can be overwritten with the Apps Script API.

[StackOverflow answer - Update an Apps Script file using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53459966/2946873)

You can also update the manifest file of an Apps Script file using the Apps Script API, and therefore, programmatically add a library, and the library version to an existing Apps Script File.